# Exact value of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

Can we find the exact value(not numerical/approximation) of sin 1?
I tried to do so by solving a cubic equation using Cardano formula but I ended up with complex nested radicals): I was told to use other methods but that won't yield exact values

Comment: Wouldn't its exact value be $\sin(1)$?

Comment: If the angle is in degree, have  a look into  http://www.efnet-math.org/Meta/sine1.htm

Comment: Isnt sin(1) an irrational?

Comment: I mean without computer software, how do you find it manually?Can you show me?

Comment: @ al Hwarizmi yes it is but can't it be represented in a form like the multiples of 3 can be...

Comment: why not 
$$1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{1}{7!}+.......$$

Comment: I prefer a closed form>>>

Comment: @Al-Hwarizmi, if I'm not severely mistaken, $\sin 1$ is trancendental, so not even an horrible expression with nested roots will give the exact value

Answer (score 1):

sin(1) is a Transcendental number.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

ie ,sin(1) is not a solution  a non-zero polynomial equation with rational coefficients.In other words sin(1) can't be expressed in closed form only using fractions and radicals.
Note: sin(a), where a is algebraic(not transcendental) ,is transcendental.

Does that help you?

Comment: @TomLynd , I didn't really understand what you meant by their solutions being incorrect.

The links are for info on transcendental number and for the reason why sin(1) is transcendental.

What I meant by sin(1) being not the solution of...... is that sin(1) can't be a solution of a polynomial equation with non-zero rational coefficients. There is no closed expression which has only radicals,fractions and algebraic numbers. There might be some expressions which involve transcendental numbers like e and $\pi$.

Comment: $\sin (1) = \Im(e^i)$

Comment: @ jaseem you better have a look at  efnet-math.org/Meta/sine1.htm – lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @TomLynd that is for one degree , or for $sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$
and $\frac{\pi}{180}$ is not algebraic.But 1(1 radian) is algebraic and therefore sin(1) is transcendental.

Answer (score 0):

```
Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 14}]
```

$$\sin (x) = x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}-\frac{x^{11}}{39916800}+\frac{x^{13}}{6227020800}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$

```
DeleteCases[CoefficientList[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 14}], x], 0]
```

$$\sin (1) = 1-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{120}-\frac{1}{5040}+\frac{1}{362880}-\frac{1}{39916800}+\frac{1}{6227020800}-...$$

$$1-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{120}-\frac{1}{5040}+\frac{1}{362880}-\frac{1}{39916800}+\frac{1}{6227020800}-... = 0.84147098480866...$$

$$\sin (1) = 0.84147098480790...$$

```
Table[(2*n - 1)!, {n, 1, 7}]
```

{1, 6, 120, 5040, 362880, 39916800, 6227020800}

Comment: He wants a closed form. My comment addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

If $1$ is degrees here's 2 closed forms:

$$\frac{1}{2}ie^{-\frac{i\pi}{180}} - \frac{1}{2}ie^{\frac{i\pi}{180}}$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[180]{-1} - 1)(\sqrt[180]{-1} + 1)(-1)^{\frac{89}{180}}$$

If $1$ is radians here's one closed form:

$$\frac{i e^{-i}}{2}-\frac{i e^i}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can. However the radicals will be nested as well as repeating. Using Precise-Rewritten method, exact value of Sin 1 degree is:
 $$√(2 - √(2  + √(2  \overline {+ √(2 + √(2  + √(2 + √(2 - √(2 - √(2 - √(2 + √(2 - √(2  - √(2  + √(2  - √(2}]/2$$

Please care the overline (not fraction) and closing brackets have collapsed by']'.

This method gives **exact values of Sine of all integer angles**. Please visit https://archive.org/details/ExactTrigonometryTableForAllAnglesFinal for the list.

Comment: Request to the scholars: You may assist me to copy edit the main document of above method. I have not idea to formatting and use of mathematical tools at all. I cannot format as online forum requires formatting the mathematics. If someone assisted me for copy edit on Precise-Rewritten method (and other new methods), every scholar may know the new idea for new method for exact trigonometric values. My (Breaking Classical Rules in Trigonometry- Mission 2050) un-skill on mathematics formating discouraging me to expose all of those new idea.